# How to include external font in WPF application without installing it

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

How to include external font in  WPF application without installing it

I tried this code

```
  System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFonts = new    System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
  privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\\Documents and Settings\\somefont.ttf");
  System.Drawing.Font font = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12);
  this.label1.Font = font;
```

It working correctly in Windows Form Application  but not in WPF.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use such XAML code:

```
<Style x:Key="Hatten">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#HATTEN" />
</Style>
```

#HATTEN - reference to hatten.tft in Resources.

Using the Style:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Style="{DynamicResource Hatten}" FontSize="72"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: The code snippet `<Style>` is incomplete/misleading. Better follow MovGP0's answer. It is basically the same but more detailed. OTF works, too.

Comment: @KyleDelaney In VS2017 you can just add a Fonts folder to your source as Resources and you can then choose the font with the drop-down menu box, looking something like this: `FontFamily="/AppName;component/Fonts/#Font Name"`

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question right? None of the answers here explains how to include EXTERNAL fonts in the project. Does that simply mean, that it's not possible to load a font dynamically during runtime into the project?

Answer (score 204):

There are two ways of doing this: One way is to package the fonts inside the application. The other way is to have the fonts in a folder. The difference is mostly the URI you need to load the files with.

#### Package with Application

1. Add a `/Fonts` folder to your solution.
2. Add the True Type Fonts (`*.ttf`) files to that folder
3. Include the files to the project
4. Select the fonts and add them to the solution
5. Set `BuildAction: Resource` and `Copy To Output Directory: Do not copy`. Your `.csproj` file should now have a section like this one:

   ```
     <ItemGroup>
      <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Bold.ttf" />
      <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf" />
      <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Italic.ttf" />
      <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Regular.ttf" />
      <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf" />
    </ItemGroup>
   ```
6. In `App.xaml` add `<FontFamily>` resources. It should look like in the following code sample. Note that the URI doesn't contain the filename when packing with the application.

   ```
    <Applicaton ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSans">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansSymbols">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Noto Sans Symbols</FontFamily>
    </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
   ```
7. Apply your fonts like this:

   ```
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="foobar" FontFamily="{StaticResource NotoSans}" 
               FontSize="10.0" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Regular" />
   ```
8. You can also set the font imperatively:

   ```
    myTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "./Fonts/#Noto Sans");
   ```

#### Copy to Output Directory

1. Add a `/Fonts` folder to your solution.
2. Add the True Type Fonts (`*.ttf`) files to that order
3. Include the files to the project
4. Select the fonts and add them to the solution
5. Set `BuildAction: Content` and `Copy To Output Directory: Copy if newer` or `Copy always`. Your `.csproj` file should now have a section like this one:

   ```
     <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Bold.ttf">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="Fonts\NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Italic.ttf">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Regular.ttf">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="Fonts\NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
   ```
6. In `App.xaml` add `<FontFamily>` resources. It should look like in the following code sample.

   ```
    <Applicaton ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansRegular">./Fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansItalic">./Fonts/NotoSans-Italic.ttf#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansBold">./Fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansBoldItalic">./Fonts/NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansSymbols">./Fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf#Noto Sans Symbols</FontFamily>
    </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
   ```
7. Apply your fonts like this:

   ```
    <TextBlock Text="foobar" FontFamily="{StaticResource NotoSansRegular}" 
               FontSize="10.0" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Regular" />
   ```

#### References

- [MSDN: Packaging Fonts with Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please clarify where `#names` are coming from and how they are constructed. Just file name without extensions preceded by `#`? Otherwise: great, detailed answer!

Comment: the string after the hash is the name of the font. 

unfortunately i don't really know how to get them except opening the font file in preview or installing it and using the font selection in an text editor. there might be a better way of doing this...

Comment: The package option does not work for me in VS2017. I followed your instructions to the letter.

Comment: Step "6" in "Package with Application" works in VS2015, but... at runtime application shows just empty squares! I removed "FontFamily" resource and specified font directly in style's Setter:
`<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./media/#FontAwesome"/>`

Comment: @KyleDelaney I followed the steps in "Package with Application" in VS2017 but it didnt work. But after I changed `build action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`, it works fantastically.

Comment: This suffers from the WPF memory leak issue as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font  as do all the other solutions given here it seems.

Comment: I tried doing this with `AddFontMemResourceEx` but seem to have issues with as can be seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964801/wpf-use-font-installed-with-addfontmemresourceex-for-process-only

Comment: @JackMiller, I know it's been a while, but I had the same question. You can get the `#names` by doing the following: Right-click the font in Windows explorer. Go to Properties -> Details -> Title.

Comment: Does the memory leak still occur when using the second method of copying to the output directory?

Comment: FYI that cryptic `#NotoSans` identifier is not driven by the file name. You need to double click on the file in Windows which opens the preview window for the font. There will be a label that says "Font name: NotoSans", it's that font name you want to use when referencing in WPF.

Comment: in VS2019 and dotnet core 3 I used ```<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/MyResourceClassLib;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>```
in step 6

Comment: There is an error: ./Fonts/NotoSans-Regular.tts should be: ./Fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf

Comment: @Rugbrød Thanks. I've fixed that in the code sample.

Comment: Am I the only one who found the instructions so unclear?
`1. Add a /Fonts folder to your solution.`
`2. Add the True Type Fonts (*.ttf) files to that order`
`3. Include the files to the project`
`4. Select the fonts and add them to the solution`
What? Aren't they the same thing? And I don't even know where the step 5 is in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 24):

The best answer to this question I found here

http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx

***SOLUTION***
It involves using even more wicked string than before but works as expected:

```
<Label FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Folder1/#Katana Sans">Text</Label>
```

Where is `Folder1` is a folder of your project where you keep a TTF file.
Three notes at the end:

1. ‘Katana Sans’ is the name of the font, not the name of the file. This is significant difference. To get the name of the font simply click the file twice. Note that spaces are *included without any changes* in this string.
2. Remember to put the hash sign ‘#’ in front of font name. It will not work otherwise.
3. Custom font may also be added to the project with ‘Build Action’ set to ‘Content’. This is not recommended approach however and for the sake of simplicity I ignored this possibility.

Some extra links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296385.aspx

Comment: Can you pick a font file and use it?

Comment: Important: "‘Katana’ is the name of the font, not the name of the file. This is significant difference. To get the name of the font simply click the file twice."

Comment: How does it know what the filename is though? Surely the file name needs to go somewhere? This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @rolls It will look through the folder for font files and pick the one that matches that name.

Comment: What made the difference for me was including spaces! My `Nunito Sans` is used as `#Nunito Sans` not `#NunitoSans` or `#Nunito_Sans` or anything else!

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to include external fonts is to

**Step 1.** Create the folder `Fonts` And add your fonts into it.

[image]

**Step 2.** Set Build action to `content` and Copy to Output Directory to `Copy always`.

[image]

**Step 3.** Build the Solution to update it with the Font directory.

**Step 4.** Use the font in your elements using `FontFamily="Fonts/#font name"`

[image]

All Done!

Thanks to [cscience](http://cscience.blog.ir/post/18) !

Comment: It worked for me, but only in designer :/ Don't forget that the font's name is case sensitive !

Comment: Didn't expected solution be like that simple.

Answer (score 10):

I did not found any answer for exactly that.
But I found a solution that I did not saw on Internet.

I followed a recommendation of doing a folder and marking all the files inside as Resources.
But I needed to enumerate them, and that was my main problem, because I need to load all to my screen without recording the name somewhere. I just want to simple drop another font to that folder and list it.

I found this as a solution to list all the files inside my resources/fonts folder

```
Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/resources/fonts/#"))
```

I expect it to help you organize your fonts.

Comment: Please add a link to the reference page for this API.

Comment: Can GetFontFamilies pick the font in the other folder?

Comment: This was extremely useful.

Answer (score 4):

I use xaml for this

```
<Window

 FontFamily ="./Fonts/#somefont"

>
```

I included the font file inside the "Fonts" folder

Answer (score 4):

First) Copy fonts to project folder like `/Resources/Fonts/` and set font-properties -> Build Action:Resource

Second) Used on code

```
FontFamily="/AssemblyNamespace;component/Resources/Fonts/IranSans/#IRANSansWeb Medium"
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution for setting the font properties to Build Action: Resource solve it for me. Only you need this in <FontFamily x:Key="myFont">pack://application:,,,/AssemlyName;component/Resources/Fonts/#IRANSansWeb </FontFamily>

Answer (score 3):

Here's What Worked for me:

(1) Add Directory to project: font

(2) Move ttf font file into font directory

(3) Add ttf font file to project

(4) Set the "Build" Property of the tff font file to "Resource"
    (Note: I used "Resource" instead of "Embedded Resource" 
     in the combobox selection.)

(5) Open the Window where you are using the font and make the 
    following changes:

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="YourFontNickName">
        pack://application:,,,/font/#NameOfFont
        <!-- Note: NameOfFont can be font by double clicking
             on font from explorer and writing down name
             of the font reported.  Its not the same
             as the file name -->
        </FontFamily>   
    </Window.Resources>


    <!-- Use font as Xaml -->
    <StackPanel>
        <Textblock FontFamily="{StaticResource YourFontNickName}">
        This is a test
        </Testblock>
        <Textblock Name="text1"/>
    </StackPanel>
...
</Window>
```

(6) If you want to change the font from code. Do this:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {

    // Use font as C# Code
    public void UpdateText1() {

            text1.Text      = "Hi There";
            FontFamily ff   = this.Resources["YourFontNickName"] 
                                as FontFamily;
            if (ff == null) {
                Messagebox.Show("Wrong Font Name", "ERROR");
                return;
            }
            text1.FontFamily = ff;
            text1.FontSize   = 30;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the solution from @movgp0 worked at first, it failed when I wanted a **Bold** text. By searching a bit more online I found the following solution that works in all cases:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <FontFamily x:Key="FiraSansBold">Fonts/FiraSansCondensed-Bold.ttf#Fira Sans Condensed</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="FiraSansBoldItalic">Fonts/FiraSansCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf#Fira Sans Condensed</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="FiraSansItalic">Fonts/FiraSansCondensed-Italic.ttf#Fira Sans Condensed</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="FiraSans">Fonts/FiraSansCondensed-Regular.ttf#Fira Sans Condensed</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

Usage: `<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource FiraSansBold}">SomeBoldedLabel</Label>`

Answer (score 2):

I have a fonts folder inside an assets folder in my project. At build time it will copy those fonts into the folder as content. Then I can simply use the following XAML to use the FontAwesome font to have an icon on my button.

```
<Button Content="&#xf0c9;" FontFamily="./assets/fonts/#FontAwesome">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **add fonts as resource item**

according to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications); you may add your desired font as application resource file by following these steps:

1. copy your font file to anywhere in your project in most cases resource files is copied into a folder named "resources" if you want to follow this, create new folder in your project and name it as "resources" then copy your font file which is usually have ttf or otf format into that folder
2. then you need to declare this file as a resource file for doing so you have two options:

   1. right click on your font file, select properties (or press F4 after selecting it) 
      and then change **"Build Action"** to **"Resource"**
   2. go into your projects directory edit `project-name.csproj` file and the 
      following tag:

      ````
      <ItemGroup>            
          <Resource Include="resources\<font-file-name>.ttf" />  
      </ItemGroup>```
      ````

finally within you application you may set font-family property like this:

```
FontFamily="./Resources/Fonts/#<font-name>"
```

be careful 'font-name' is **different** from font-file-name you may open font file and check for font name property (in Microsoft Window)

[image: fetching font name by opening font file]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get this to work as well with a different font, 
it only worked for me in this format with the ./Fonts

`<FontFamily x:Key="NotoSans">pack://application:,,,./Fonts/#Noto Sans</FontFamily>`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, Really easy:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" FontSize="24" Margin="256,25,178,289" Text="gg" FontFamily="/FontTest;component/#Arvo"></TextBlock>
```

When you import a font, vs will gonna include it in font list.