# Installing Custom fonts into System

Tags: wpf, fonts

I am having custom fonts(.ttf file) in my WPF application. I am able to use those fonts in my application but now I need to install these fonts in system. How do I install custom fonts into machine from my WPF C# code?

Comment: Take at look at the accepted answer of this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it

Comment: i am trying to install in C:/Windows/Fonts folder and I'm getting Syatem.AccessViolation Exception. How do i resolve that?