# Segue Icon in TextBlock with Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to make a Grid with an Icon in it. I am storing the string representation of the icon in a database, and trying to display these icons in a GridHub by binding to the Icon property (a string) on my viewmodel.

When I use this xaml, I get the actual text displayed in the grid

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Icon}"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
    FontSize="100"
    TextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Foreground="DarkGray"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Some Label"/>
```

But this displays the icon as expected

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xE1D4;"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
    FontSize="100"
    TextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Foreground="DarkGray"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Some Label"/>
```

My Model looks like:

```
 public class PermissionGroup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier for the group.
    /// </summary>
    public string PermissionGroupId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the group
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The page associated with the permission group
    /// </summary>
    public string PageName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The icon that will be shown on the PermissionHub page
    /// </summary>
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A description of the permissions in the group
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The permissions associated with this permission group
    /// </summary>
    public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } 
}
```

and my viewmodel just contains a list of these objects.

In my database I have tried storing the following:

1. `&#xE1D4;`
2. \uE1D4 (has to be escaped to get in the db)
3. 57812 (the result of `char.Parse("\uE1D4")`)

and none of these has resulted in the icon being displayed correctly!

[The output of first XAML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iytWs.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to decode the html encoded string. For instance you can try this very rough example:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public PermissionGroup PG {get; set;}
        public ViewModel()
        {
            PG = new PermissionGroup();
            PG.Icon= System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xE1D4;");
        }
    }




public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }


<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PG.Icon}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

or

```
<Style x:Key="Segoe">
    <Setter x:Name="Segoe" Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#Segoe UI Symbol" />
</Style>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding PG.Icon}"
            Style="{DynamicResource Segoe}"
```

A font viewer is available [here](http://us.fontviewer.de/Download/), in case you need one.

EDIT: anyway the unicode escape sequence should work better than the html encoding, that's why I'm suggesting to double check with a font viewer and to link the font ttf as a resource. 
You can also add a button to analyse the unicode conversion of your xaml text, when directly entered without binding. Something like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txname.Text);
    char[] stringChars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(stringBytes);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Array.ForEach<char>(stringChars, c => builder.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X}", (int)c));
    Debug.WriteLine(builder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Giulio, I will give this a try. I am not sure HTML decode is the right thing to do since I am not creating HTML (its XAML), but I will see if there is a decoding mechanism I can use. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried those lines of code before posting them, of course :-) Besides that specific string and regarding your comment/doubt, now I've found also this external link from msdn (about xaml) that appears to confirm my hint: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/ee719905-bb65-41f1-9885-ab70775d71c5/textblock-encoded-text

Comment: You may have a look also at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6856459/4569980) answer about including an external font in xaml