# Add font to my application in order to verify that in the machine that running my app this font will not be missing

Tags: wpf, fonts

in my `application` in am using specific `font` and i am notice that in other machines that running my `application` this font is missing and in this case my application using different `font` (maybe default one ) so i wonder how to add this specific font to my application.

**Edit**

After try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it) solution:

Declate `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyFont">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#BuxtonSketch.ttf" />
</Style>
```

`BuxtonSketch.ttf` locate in my `resources` folder, and inside my label:

```
<Label Content="Test"  FontSize="35" Style="{StaticResource MyFont}"/>
```

My `label` gets different `font`, did i miss something ?

i also try:

```
<Style x:Key="MyFont" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Resources/#BuxtonSketch.ttf" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it

Comment: Posted the answer with the new information that you provided, please let me know if it worked for you. You are using the wrong name for the font in your style, it should be the font name, not the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the folder in your solution named `Resources`. Put the font file `BuxtonSketch.ttf` inside it and add it to the solution, set build action to Resource.

This is important, open the TTF file from Windows, and check the `Font name` value, this is the value that you need to use in your code. I guess it will be `Buxton Sketch`, so you write that value, without the extension.

Define the style in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyFont">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#Buxton Sketch"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then apply the style to control:

```
<Label Content="Test" FontSize="35" Style="{StaticResource MyFont}"/>
```

**EDIT**: Corrected the font name

Comment: i changed build action to Resource and copy your code and still nothing, i didn't understand how to check the font name value

Comment: Double-click the TTF file from Windows explorer :) I downloaded the font myself, the name that you need to use is `Buxton Sketch`. Made the edit to the answer with the correct name.

Comment: Paths are case sensitive, make sure your folder is named `Resources`, not `resources`.

Comment: OK this works fine now, the problem was because i mover the build from resources to none, thanks a lot for your help