# wpf embedded font not shown while running

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, fonts, font-embedding

I embedded Google's Material Design icon font into my WPF project by adding it into project resources.

The font displayed correctly in Visual Studio designer but showed only tofus (something like ``) while running.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what in `App.xaml` code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="MaterialIcon">/ExampleProject;component/Resources/#Material Icons</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

And here's how I declared the button:

```
<Button x:Name="ExampleButton" Content="&#xE0C3;" FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialIcon}"/>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screentshot of designer and program]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmmmmm, try to see this post:
[How to include external font in WPF application without installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it).

I think that the Uri used for specify the font path is not correct. In this case, you get a different behavior between design-time and runtime.