# Use Font in WPF with Specific Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When the program starts I make the download of the font to a specific path.

It's

> "C:/Videowall_INFO/fonts/MyFont.ttf"

then I try to use it in XAML like this:

```
FontFamily="C:/Videowall_INFO/fonts/MyFont.ttf#MyFont"
```

Am I missing something?
Becasuse its not showing in Designer or Runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external font in WPF application without installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it)?

Comment: But I need to download it every time the App Starts.

Comment: Did you try putting this in:<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="MyFont">C:/Videowall_INFO/fonts/MyFont.ttf#MyFont</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources> and referencing with FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFont}" - in a little test Project there was no Exception thrown as long as the font is not referenced by the StaticResource and the file does not exist

Answer (score 0):

So I just found that the problem was the ".ttf" file that was corrupted after the download.

And this is the correct way of setting the path:

```
FontFamily="C:/Videowall_INFO/fonts/#MyFont"
```

Just removed the "MyFont.ttf" and it Works fine!

Thanks!