# Add external font failed but for all fonts

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

So i try to add external `font` int my `application` using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it)

Steps:

Add a /Fonts folder to your solution.
Add the True Type Fonts (*.ttf) files to that folder
Include the files to the project
Select the fonts and add them to the solution
Set BuildAction: Resource and Copy To Output Directory: Do not copy. Your .csproj file should now should have a section like this one:

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Bold.ttf" />
  <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf" />
  <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Italic.ttf" />
  <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSans-Regular.ttf" />
  <Resource Include="Fonts\NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In App.xaml add  Resources. It should look like in the following code sample. Note that the URI doesn't contain the filename when packing with the application.

```
<Applicaton ...>
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSans">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Noto Sans</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="NotoSansSymbols">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Noto Sans Symbols</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Apply your Fonts like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="foobar" FontFamily="{StaticResource NotoSans}" 
           FontSize="10.0" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Regular" />
```

So i download several fonts but this works only for some of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: how does "fail/work" show? files not included when published, fonts not used although selected in a control, runtime exception, ...?

Comment: I follow all the steps above, i just see the default font, the other font that work so i can see this font