# C# custom fonts issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I am trying to use a custom font on my project so everyone can see it, I tried what was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it) and that didn't work (the font wouldn't change), so I opened a new project and tried it there and it worked, so on my current project it doesn't work and on the new one it does and I don't want to restart the project because I have so mush stuff in it. Please can someone help

Comment: Could you add the code of the project where it didn’t work? Otherwise it is quite hard to get an answer

Comment: Hi so, Ive just restarted c# Blend and it does seem to work but only when i run the app, but I cant preview it in the editor e.g. [here](https://imgur.com/PJ3znzP)