# Include Fonts in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, font-family

Ok so everything I've been trying is not loading my fonts correctly, I've added them to the .csproj file which was done by switching `copy to output directory` so this is what it looks like

```
<Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-Black.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-BlackItalic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-ExtraLightItalic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-Light.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-LightItalic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Fonts\SourceSansPro-SemiBoldItalic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
```

Then I've added the references inside my `ui-dictionary` which looks like

```
    <FontFamily x:Key="Black" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Black</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="BlackItalic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-BlackItalic</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Bold" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Bold</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="BoldItalic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-BoldItalic</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="ExtraLight" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-ExtraLight</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="ExtraLightItalic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-ExtraLightItalic</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Italic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Italic</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Light" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="LightItalic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-LightItalic</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Regular" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Regular</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="SemiBold" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-SemiBold</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="SemiBoldItalic" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-SemiBoldItalic</FontFamily>
```

But everytime I've tried to use it fonts do not load. So I've tried different methods in the uri

```
<!-- First Method -->
    <FontFamily x:Key="Light" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf#SourceSansPro-Light</FontFamily>

<!-- Second Method -->
<FontFamily x:Key="Light" >pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Light</FontFamily>

<!-- Third Method -->
<FontFamily x:Key="Light" >/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Light</FontFamily>

<!-- Third Method -->
<FontFamily x:Key="Light" >/Resources/Fonts/#SourceSansPro-Light</FontFamily>

<!-- Fourth Method -->
<FontFamily x:Key="Light" >/Resources/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf#SourceSansPro-Light</FontFamily>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have You tried to set up properties on font -> Build Action = Resource ?

Comment: Yes they're all set to Resource

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it).

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I tried that and getting a exception error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Style' to type 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`

Comment: Can You check this link please -> [WPF fonts](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/embedding-fonts/) meaby some step is missing, and FYI name of font "#SourceSansPro-Black" is a name when You open the font in external program (Name from title bar) not name of file, please check it also

Comment: I figured it out, I had to go to Windows->Fonts and copy the font name exactly, not the filename. So `#SourceSansPro-Light` should be `Source Sans Pro Light`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedding fonts in WPF as resources, is pretty simple. However, there are few gotchas that you need to be aware of.

Here is a step by step process that I followed in a sample app:

Added `Resources`/`Fonts` folders to my project

Dragged the Source Sans Pro `.ttf` files into the `Fonts` folder

Visual Studio automatically set their `Build Action` to `Resource`

Note: You don't need to copy them to the output directory if they are being used as resources

Created a `Fonts.xaml` `ResourceDictionary` with the following code

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="Regular">pack://application:,,,/WpfApp4;component/Resources/Fonts/#Source Sans Pro</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="Black">pack://application:,,,/WpfApp4;component/Resources/Fonts/#Source Sans Pro Black</FontFamily>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I merged in the `Fonts.xaml` resources into my `App.xaml` file.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp4.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Fonts.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

*The first problem you have is an incorrect Pack Uri format.*

pack://application:,,,/**YourAppNamespace;component**/Resources/Fonts/#Font Family Name

*The second problem you have is an incorrect font family name*

The font family name is usually **not** the same as the .ttf file name!

To get the right family name, I highly recommend using the [dp4 Font Viewer](https://us.fontviewer.de/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I've never used `;component` what is that exactly? In terms of the URI format. Is that just saying that it's a component?

Comment: `;component` is helpful when you're dealing with an external resources assembly. However, I have found that using it all the time solves a lot of resource resolution issues I run into.

Comment: @Keithernet you never showed your final, working implementation or even how to do it. You show how to implement the resource dictionary, but provided no XAML or Code-Behind on how to use it. Could you edit your answer to elaborate this possibly? Showing a working implementation in the end of your answer would be the icing this cake needs.

Comment: @DeeJayh here's an example of how to use the font: `<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Regular}" Text="Hello World" />`