# How can i change font family in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I need help with changeing the font of my label in wpf.

I opened a new folder called fonts, i put in there a font i found online, and now i want to change the content's font to the font i found online. I've tried looking online but i couldnt find any solutions about that.

I have another proggram which in there, it actually did change for me, and i did the exact same thing now, i really dont know what am i doing wrong.

I dont know why the font dosent change. can someone help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiroL.png

Comment: In order for you to be able to use that font, it must be installed on the machine where your program will run.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `In order for you to be able to use that font, it must be installed on the machine` I've used fonts without requiring installation.

Comment: @zaggler: How did you determine that it wasn't installed?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I didn't have to, it was a font that I created for testing. Anyways, @@Azu [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912794/1797425) it may be useful.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for using label I would suggest you use a textblock instead. When you set content of a label to a string then a textblock is created by the label and it's text set to that string. There are some styling subtleties can cause complications.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the Microsoft documentation for packaging fonts with a WPF application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You're almost there. In your screenshot, it looks like you may have made a typo when specifying the `FontFamily`.